# Access the Dictionary From Json URL

Tags: ios, json

I am Using URL For Access JSON file
I get this From Following code

```
    NSData* data=[jsonString dataUsingEncoding: [NSString defaultCStringEncoding] ];
    NSError *error;  //where jsonString is string of URL
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];


    if (jsonDictionary==nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error::Loading");

}else
{

    NSArray *array = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"categories"];
    for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dic setValue:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"cat_id"] forKey:@"cat_id"];
        [dic setValue:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"cat_name"] forKey:@"cat_name"];
        [dic setValue:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"cat_image"] forKey:@"cat_image"];
        [dic setValue:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"cat_list"] forKey:@"cat_list"];
        [newsArray addObject:dic];

        [categoryArry addObject:[dic valueForKey:@"cat_name"]];
        [categoryId addObject:[dic valueForKey:@"cat_id"]];
        [categoryImage addObject:[dic valueForKey:@"cat_image"]];
        [categoryList addObject:[dic valueForKey:@"cat_list"]];
        [dic release];


    }
}
```

and get json Structure Like This

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "cat_id": "15",
            "cat_name": "Shop",
            "cat_image": null,
            "cat_list": [
                {
                    "sub_cat_name": "New Arrivals",
                    "Cat_Data": [
                        {
                            "prod_name": "Generals Coat Biege",
                            "prod_price": "215.0000",
                            "prod_image": "honey_beau_lookbook_winter13_febmarch-24.jpg"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

categoryArry contain only ine value "Shop"
but i want to access "sub_cat_name" in categoryArry and skip the Shop Level....

In  short I want to store "sub_cat_name" in to categoryArry.

Comment: And is there anything that prevents you from doing so?

Comment: I want to just Skip "cat_name":"Shop" Level  and use from "sub_cat_name" .....

Comment: Yes, I understand that, what is your problem?

Comment: Why are you forming separate arrays for storing name, id, image etc. It is a well structured data. You need to make proper data models to map them. Keep the data in one object itself. You can other ways to get the desired values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you just need to do:

```
NSArray *catlist = [dic valueForKey:@"cat_list"]
NSDictionary *firstcat = [catlist objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *subcatname = [firstcat valueForKey:@"sub_cat_name"];
```

This assumes of course that you have at least one item in the `cat_list` array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 3rd party library called [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to make JSON requests and parse the response.

Here's an example:

```m
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:@"http://yoursite.com"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                             path:@"blah/path"
                                                       parameters:@{@"jsonKey":@"jsonValue"}];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                     JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *res, id json) {

                                     // Use the json here    
                                     json[@"categories"][0][@"cat_list"];

                               } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id json) {
                                     //Handle Errors
                               }];
[operation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

At your code replace:

```
  [categoryArry addObject:[dic valueForKey:@"cat_name"]];
```

by

```
   [categoryArry addObject:[[dic valueForKey:@"cat_list"][0]] valueForKey:@"sub_cat_name"];
```

Anyway you could use the `jsonDictionary` directly instead of creating another `dict`.